# What fraction of finitely presented groups have unsolvable word problem?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, computability, word-problem, geometric-group-theory

> What fraction of finitely presented groups have unsolvable word problem?

I suspect the answer is "almost all" for some suitable notion, but I can't find any results on the topic. Any references you have would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: There are complicated ways of making this precise, but "most" finitely presented groups are word-hyperbolic and thus automatic.

Comment: All the issue is to define "almost all". One way is to take $k$ generators (fixed) and $f(n)$ relators random of size $\le n$ and let $n$ tend to infinity. This includes the most naive model (say $f(n)$ constant), and also Gromov's model with $f(n)=(2k-1)^{dn}$, $d$ a fixed parameter. But even in such cases, choosing the relators randomly in a ball is a somewhat artificial choice. So "*most*" means, in a sence, "*most* in the models studied so far". Also in such a model it's not "most finitely presented groups" but "most finite presentations".

Comment: There are also results that say roughly that for almost all group presentations and for almost all words $w$  in the generators we can decide whether $w$ is the identity in that group, but that is essentially because most groups are not perfect and most words do not lie in the commutator subgroup.

Comment: "Most groups are not perfect": in Gromov's density model: generically presentations define groups that are perfect or $Z/2$ abelianization, I think.

Comment: @YCor Well, in the $0$-density model you may have more generators than relations (as here you essentially first pick the number of generators and relations), so in this case the groups are not perfect. On the other hand, Theorem 36 (p46) of Ollivier's book provides perfect groups, but they are not produced in the density model (unless I am missunderstanding something).

Comment: Yes of course I mean positive density (density zero is not really Gromov's).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a well-developed theory of "random groups". As you specifically ask for a reference, a basic reference is Ollivier's *A January 2005 invitation to random groups*, which you can find on his webpage [here](http://www.yann-ollivier.org/rech/publs/randomgroups.pdf). At the moment, the theory explained in Ollivier's book is the best you are going to get. On the one hand, it doesn't answer your question because, as YCor mentioned in the comments to the question, it is really the theory of random *presentations*. On the other hand, hyperbolic groups have soluble word problem and all the "random groups" defined in the various known models (as of 2005) are all hyperbolic (see p27, line 1 of Ollivier's book for the appropriate quote!). Hence, in a certain sense the "random groups" of Ollivier's book do answer your question.

---

I now want to give you a flavour of what we mean by a "random group". I'll describe the "few relator" model, which is also called the "$0$-density" model. This is the most basic model, which is why I am typing it up now. It has its advantages and disadvantages. This post is not meant as an endorsement for this model :-)

What follows uses the $C'(\lambda)$ small cancellation conditions, $\lambda\leq1/6$. For more information either Google "small cancellation theory" or see Lyndon and Schupp's book *Combinatorial Group Theory*, Springer (1977). Basically, this is an easily-checkable condition on the relators which implies that the underlying group has decidable word problem (in a really pretty way), and is in fact hyperbolic.

Fix two numbers $m$ and $n$. We are going to see what properties a group defined by a generic $m$-generator, $n$-relator presentation $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_m\mid r_1, \ldots, r_n\rangle$ possesses by looking at relators of bounded length $t$ and then increasing the ball which contains them. The following lemma is due to Arzhantseva and Ol'shanskii* (I believe 0.2.A of Gromov's seminal *Hyperbolic groups* essay is analogous, although I do not have this to hand)):

> **Lemma.** Among all finite sequences $\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$ of freely and cyclically reduced words whose lengths are at most $t$, the fraction of sequences satisfying the small cancellation $C'(\lambda)$ condition is $\geq1-a(2m-1)^{-\lambda t/5}$ for $t\geq a$, where $a>0$ and depends on $m$, $n$ and $\lambda$.

Group presentations $\langle x_1, \ldots, x_m\mid r_1, \ldots, r_n\rangle$ are associated in an obvious way with sequences $\{r_1, \ldots, r_n\}$ of freely and cyclically reduced words. Therefore, fixing some $\lambda\leq1/6$, by letting $t\rightarrow\infty$ in the above lemma we see that "almost all" $m$-generator, $n$-relator presentations satisfy $C'(\lambda)$. By unioning these models, it follows that "almost all" finite presentations satisfy $C'(\lambda)$. As we chose $\lambda\leq1/6$, these groups are hyperbolic and have decidable word problem (in fact the solution is super nice).

We can then address the question in your title. Getting a fraction is stronger than just saying "almost all".

> **Theorem.** The fraction of finite presentations defining groups with unsolvable word problem is $0$.

*Proof.* This is because the fraction satisfying $C'(1/6)$ is $1$, because $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}1-a(2m-1)^{-\lambda t/5}=1$.

*The citation here is not short: G. N. Arzhantseva, A. Yu. Ol’shanski˘ı, *The class of groups all of whose subgroups with lesser number of generators are free is generic*, Mat. Zametki 59 (1996), no. 4, 489–496; English translation in Math. Notes 59 (1996), no. 3–4, 350–355.

Comment: I'm really glad I asked this question now! These results are extremely surprising, haha. Will Lyndon and Schupp's book contain information on other notions of "random group"?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor No. Lyndon and Schupp is a classical book from the 70s. I believe the study of random groups started with Gromov in his 1987 essay "Hyperbolic groups", but it's definitely a "post Lyndon and Schupp" theory. I cited Lyndon and Schupp because it is the standard reference for small cancellation theory.

Comment: (Ollivier's book contains other models of random groups though. It's the place to start if you are interested in this topic.)

Comment: Whoops, I had completely forgotten about the first section of your (excellent) answer by the end. Thanks again!